# Bootstrap modal not replacing content for different link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have successfully added a modal from external link in my web-app, but now when I click the button to launch the modal the content of the previous modal is launched. I want it to be reloaded every time.

This is the button for launching the modal.

```
<button href="/forum/flag_post/0838024b-f210-4f4d-ac53-fd4ade12d533"  class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Report</button>
```

There are mutliple buttons like this and each one has a different `href` and once I press a button and close the modal, the same modal content is lauched every button. I don't want that. I want the modal content to be loaded freshly from the URL.

This is the modal class:

```
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<!-- Content will be loaded here from "remote.php" file -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#modalLinks a").click(function () {
            var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
            $(".modalContent").load(addressValue);
        });
    });
<script>

<div id="modalLinks">
    <a href="/forum/flag_post/777b1580-572f-41a4-80c8-f2ac58ac49ad" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Report</a>
    <a href="/forum/flag_post/somewhereElse" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Somewhere</a>
    <a href="/forum/flag_post/somewhereTooFar" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Somewhere too far</a>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is whenever you click on a link, JQuery update the modal content with ajax.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Will it work if there are multiple buttons with `id="linkToSomewhere"`

Comment: I have one report button for one post with different link for each post. There are multiple posts.

Comment: Id must be identical for each element, let me edit my answer

Comment: @Kotlinboy Now it must work for every link inside div with `modalLinks` id

Comment: Do you mean `.modal-content`?

Comment: Isn't having more than one element with the same `id` invalid?

Comment: Fixed by changing `id=modalLinks` to `class=modal-link`

Comment: I've included links inside a div with `modalLinks` ID. Because probably you don't want to all links in your page (for example links in menu) load into modal content :) when you use ID you must use `#` and whenever you use class you need to use `.` I will update my answer once again to help you understand better @Kotlinboy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163767/discussion-between-kotlinboy-and-masoud-keshavarz).